# Proving that $I_{m\geq S}E(X\mid \mathcal{F}_{S})$ is $\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge m}$ measurable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $S$ be a stopping time.

I'm trying to prove that $I_{m\geq S}E(X\mid \mathcal{F}_{S})$ is $\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge m}$ measurable.

My try:

$I_{m\geq S}E(X\mid \mathcal{F}_{S})=I_{S=S\wedge m}E(X\mid \mathcal{F}_{S})=I_{S=S\wedge m}E(X\mid \mathcal{F}_{S\wedge m})$.

Now, I would only need to prove that $I_{S=S\wedge m}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{S\wedge m}$ measurable. For this, I need to prove that $\{S=S\wedge m\} \in \mathcal{F}_{S\wedge m}$.

By its definition, $\{S=S\wedge m\} \in \mathcal{F}_{S\wedge m}$ is equivalent to $\forall_t \{S=S\wedge m\}\cap\{S\wedge m \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$.

$\{S=S\wedge m\}\cap\{S\wedge m \leq t\}= \{S\leq t\}\cap\{S\wedge m \leq t\}$ and by definition of stopping times, both sets belong to $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Edit: Given the comment by Kavi, here's my attempt at the correction.

If $m\leq t$, then $\{S\leq m\} \in \mathcal{F}_{m} \subset \mathcal{F}_{t}$.

If $m>t$, then $\{S=S\wedge m\}\cap\{S\wedge m \leq t\}=\{S\leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$

And so, $\{S=S\wedge m\}\cap\{S\wedge m \leq t\}=(\{S\leq m\}\cap \{m\leq t\} ) \cup (\{S\leq t\}\cap \{m> t\})$ belong to $\mathcal{F}_{t}$.

Comment: Your last equality is not correct. You can only say that the left side is contained in the right side.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hi thanks for your comment. I agree with you. Is there a way to still preserve my conclusion?